# Hapijs : How to send POST objects array in POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-post, postman, hapi.js

can help me how to send POST request in POSTMAN for following array of objects and validate with Joi in hapi server?

```
var payload = [{ name: 'TEST Name 1',
      answer: 'TEST Answer 1',
      category: 'food',
      score: 10,
      question_id: '10001',
      created_at: '2016-07-10T20:11:34+00:00' },
    { name: 'TEST Name 1',
      answer: 'TEST Answer 1',
      category: 'food',
      score: 10,
      question_id: '10001',
      created_at: '2016-07-10T20:11:34+00:00' }];
```

Below is sample Joi validate in hapi-server.

```
validate: {
      payload: {
        answers: {
          arraySchema: Joi.array().items(Joi.object().keys({
                  name: Joi.string(),
                  answer: Joi.string(),
                  category: Joi.string(),
                  score: Joi.number().integer(),
                  question_id: Joi.string(),
                  created_at: Joi.date()
                }))
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In the Body of your post request, instead of using `form-data`, you can use `raw`.  Just `JSON.stringify()` that array of objects you have and throw it in the raw section and you should be set.

Comment: Gotcha, Thanks much!